# Do you only need to use FindControl on a nested control if the control it is in implements INamingContainer?

Tags: c#

I have a GridView which has a Panel inside of it and inside of that Panel is another GridView.  I don't think Panel implements INamingContainer, so is that the reason why I don't need to Find the Panel control first and then find the nested GridView within the Panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, INamingContainer defines the context where the controls need to have unique ids.